# Java Generics: What is the intention of this pattern?

Tags: java, generics, jenkins-api

I have seen this in the Jenkins API, and I would like to understand the purpose of this pattern. I cannot grasp the meaning of `JobT` and `RunT`.

`Class Run<JobT extends Job<JobT,RunT>,RunT extends Run<JobT,RunT>>`

From: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a somewhat complicated but reasonably common way to define two types that strongly relate to each other and always should be used in tandem.

`JobT` is the specific job type that both knows about itself (`Job<JobT`) and also knows about `RunT` (`,RunT`).

In exactly the same way the `RunT` can know about itself and the `JobT`.

This ensures that `Run.getNextBuild()` can always return the specific type of itself (without the `RunT` type it would have to return a generic `Run`) and that `getParent()` can return the specific `JobT`.

Without *both* of these parameters a code like this wouldn't work:

```
SomeSpecificRun myRun = ...;
SomeSpecificJob myJob = myRun.getParent();
SomeSpecificRun previousSuccessfulRun = myJob.getPreviousBuild();
```

Unless `Job` "knows of" (i.e. has a type parameter of) the run type **and** `Run` "knows of" (i.e. has a type parameter of) the job type, this could couldn't reference the specific Run/Job classes and would quickly devolve into manual casts to the specific class.